# Small gaps between primes and arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory, prime-gaps

It was proved in Polignac Numbers Conjectures of Erdos on Gaps Between Primes Arithmetic Progressions in Primes and the Bounded Gap Conjecture for János Pintz, using Bounded gaps between primes for Zhang, the following theorem (theorem 2.12)
[image]

Are we able to re-formulate the same result by choosing $d \le 246$
Using Variants of the Selberg sieve and bounded intervals containing many primes for DHJ Polymath?.

[image]

Comment: The stated theorem is clearly wrong. If we fix some positive integer $d$, then the length of the progression $p,p+d,p+2d,p+3d,...$ containing only primes is always limited.

Comment: @Peter it was proved in the article mentioned above

Comment: @Peter Easy to misunderstand, but I think what is meant is that there is a $d$ such that for every $k$ there is an arithmetic progression $p_{\kappa} = p_0 + \kappa\cdot m_k$, $0 \leqslant \kappa < k$, of primes, such that for every $\kappa$, $(p_{\kappa}, p_{\kappa} + d)$ is a pair of consecutive primes.